# Reverse for with no arguments not found for URL

Tags: django

I am attempting to create a view that allows users to delete a build log. On the view that shows the delete button with a link to the delete page I am getting the error

```
Reverse for 'build-log-delete' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/build\\-log/(?P<pkz>[0-9]+)/delete$']
```

If I understand this error correctly its because I am not passing paramaters in the url.

```
<a class="delete-btn" href="{% url 'build-log-delete' %}">Delete</a>
```

However I do not understand why I need to pass parameters in the URL as I am not passing any new values into the URL and if so what parameters I would pass. Do I have to re pass the previous two?

urls

```
path('post/<int:pk>/build-log/<int:pkz>/', views.BuildLogDisplay, name='build-log-view'),

path('post/<int:pk>/build-log/<int:pkz>/delete', views.BuildLogDelete, name='build-log-delete') #error
```

views

```
def BuildLogDisplay(request, pk, pkz ):
    post = BuildLog.objects.filter(post_id=pk)    
    log = BuildLog.objects.get(pk=pkz)

    context = {
         'post':post, 'log':log       
        }

    return render(request, 'blog/buildlog.html', context)  


def BuildLogDelete(request):             
    context = { }
    return render(request, 'blog/BuildLogDelete.html', context)
```

full template

```
    <div class="row">
    <article class="cars-article">
        <div class="flex">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ log.author.profile.image.url }}" />
            <div>
                <a class="article-title">{{ log.title }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            {% if log.author == user %}
            <a class="update-btn" href=""> Update</a>
            <a class="delete-btn" href="{% url 'build-log-delete' %}">Delete</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <hr class="solid">

        <p class="article-content">{{ log.content | safe}}</p>    
    </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in you code. You are not passing args in `BuildLogDelete` view but in url you are using those arguments. So the correct view should look like this.

```
def BuildLogDelete(request,pk,pkz):
    # delete code
    # write here
```

Next mistake which i can see is you are assigning queryset rather than object for the `post` key in `BuildLogDisplay` view. You should assign object.

```
post = BuildLog.objects.get(post_id=pk)
```

Lastly your original error mentioned in the question is because your `build-log-delete` url expects two arguments i.e `pk` and `pkz` but you haven't passed them in template. So it should be like this.

`<a class="delete-btn" href='{% url "build-log-delete" pk=post.post_id pkz=log.pk %}'>Delete</a>`

I would highly suggest you to look for already given generic views like `ListView`, `TemplateView`, `CreateView`, `UpdateView` and `DeleteView`. This will prevent you from reinventing the wheel

Ref: [Django Class Based Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For `post = BuildLog.objects.get(post_id=pk)` when I use that I get the error `MultipleObjectsReturned` thats why i was doing it the other way.